# I'm looking for a way to convert char to bin array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, char, bit

I'm trying to find the way to convert char to bit array, mess a bit with it and then convert it back. All answers are about string to byte.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `BitArray`?

If so:

```
char c = 'X';
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(c);
BitArray bits = new BitArray(bytes);
```

Comment: It's not like "gimmeh code" - I'm looking for a way, not a certain code. Answer like "use method x" would be sufficient.

Comment: @Areth If the answer just said "use BitConverter and BitArray" it should just be a comment rather than an answer - that's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Dear @Areth, "Use method @MatthewWatson"  ;-)